# How to change the distance between y axis points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, I have done a lot of searching but cant find the answer. I am using matplotlib to generate plots for some data but need to space out the distance between the points on the y axis.

So this is how I have it currently [matlibplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWWin.png)

And I want it to be spaced out like this [sampleplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6KHx.png)

```
ratioticks = (0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1)
line = plt.plot(x, ratioy, label='BCR:ABL1 ratio(IS)')
line2 = plt.plot(x, sensy, label='Sensitivity of Detection (1/ABL1)')
line3 = plt.plot(x, sensx, label='Target Sensitivity')
line4 = plt.plot(x, mrx, label='MMR')
plt.setp(line, color='r', linewidth=2.0)
plt.setp(line2, color='g', linewidth=2.0)
plt.setp(line3, color='b', linewidth=2.0)
plt.setp(line3, color='m', linewidth=2.0)
plt.grid(which='both')
plt.yticks(ratioticks)
plt.ylabel('Ratio on Log Scale')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Level of BCR:ABL1 normalised to ABL1 on the International Scale (IS)')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like your y-axis isn't a logarithmic scale.
try `ax.set_yscale("log")` for that axis. Difficult to be definitive without seeing the code that you've made the plot with.

Comment: Have edited to add the code

Comment: Yeah, looks like the y-axis is linear, so you've just applied logarithmic ticks to a linear scale so it's spacing them appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a call to:

```
plt.yscale("log")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that before and it didnt plot correctly but turned out its cause there was a zero in the dataset so was a data problem. whoops!